# Stripe Error Unrecognized request URL (POST: /v1/customers/)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am attempting to update a card for a customer but I keep running into the following error:

Unrecognized request URL (POST: /v1/customers/). If you are trying to list objects, remove the trailing slash. If you are trying to retrieve an object, make sure you passed a valid (non-empty) identifier in your code. Please see https://stripe.com/docs or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.

```
public function create_payment( $meta ) {
        
        try {
            
            return \Stripe\Customer::update( $meta );
        } catch ( \Exception $e ) {

            return $this->get_error( $e );
        }
        
    }
```

The array I am passing is:

```
Array ( [0] => cus_Ki70TVjxbH5Iyj [1] => Array ( [default_source] => card_1K2iuHEnwinWAjhjSN00IXjp ) )
```

Comment: Log out $meta, that variable is `null` or uninitialized probably.

Comment: The array Array ( [0] => cus_Ki70TVjxbH5Iyj [1] => Array ( [default_source] => card_1K2iuHEnwinWAjhjSN00IXjp ) ) is $meta

Comment: when you pass something to `\Stripe\Customer::update()` you are supposed to pass a String that represents a Customer ID e.g. cus_123. Your code is passing a PHP array. You need to parse out just the Customer ID and pass that into the ::update() call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a trailing slash was being passed to the API and that was causing the error. It is fixed now